# How can I make Java detect a backreference while respecting word boundaries?

Tags: java, regex

My task is to create a regex with which I can detect the same word occurring multiple times and replace all of them with the first occurrence.

What I have come up with so far is: `(\\b\\w+\\b)\\s{1}\\1`

However, this detects e.g. the second `horse` in `horse horseracing`. I only want to detect exact matches, i.e. I want the word boundaries I supplied to be respected.

To my surprise, `(\\b\\w+\\b)\\s{1}\\1` seems to be the same as `\\b(\\w+)\\b\\s{1}\\1`.

Some example replacements:

`Goodbye bye bye world world world` -> `Goodbye bye world`
`Sam went went to to to his business` -> `Sam went to his business`
`Reya is is the the best player in eye eye game` -> `Reya is the best player in eye game`

The three above work fine, however:

`in inthe` becomes `inthe` instead of `in inthe`. What should I modify so that the word boundaries are respected?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repeat the word boundary:

```
"\\b(\\w+)\\s\\1\\b"
                ^^^
```

See the [`\b(\w+)\s\1\b` regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QRh3Ko/1).

The mere fact that you put the word boundary *pattern* inside a capturing group does not mean the word boundary semantics are passed with the backreference. The backreference only stores the *text value* captured, and not the context it was matched in.

Besides, some word boundaries are present in the pattern implicitly: between `\w+` and `\s` and between `\s` and `\1` (whitespace is a non-word char). Thus, you just need a `\b` in front, and a `\b` at the end of the pattern.